# Verifying linearly independent set

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

> Consider the curve $a \subset \mathbb{R^3}$ given by the formula
>   $$a(t) = (2t,t^2,t^3/3)$$
>   where $t \in  \mathbb{R}$
>   Verify that $\{a',a''\}$ is a linearly independent set for each $t$.

Comment: what is the meaning of $$a',a''$$? the derivative with respect to $$t$$?

Comment: Yes, the first and second derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then we have $$a'(t)=(2,2t,t^2)$$ and $$a''(t)=(0,2,2t)$$
if these vectors are linear independet, then must have the equationsystem
$$\alpha(2,2t,t^2)+\beta(0,2,2t)=(0,0,0)$$ has only the solution $$\alpha=0,\beta=0$$

Comment: Ok this is indeed what I did. Thank you for the response, I needed the confidence in my thinking. Ill tick in 2 minutes.